# What is Microsoft.Bcl.Async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

What is Microsoft.Bcl.Async and what is it used for?

I've read on [the package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) that:

> This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords.

But as could see my VS2012 supports **async** and **await** without any extra package.

So should I install the package for my C# 4.5 'async' project?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C# 4.5". `async` / `await` requires C# 5, and some framework types. Those framework types are provided out-of-the-box in .NET 4.5, or as drop-in additions in .NET 4.0 (via `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`)

Comment: @leppie Why isn't [tag:visual-studio-2012] relevant? The package description specifically talks about VS 2012 (and VS 2010).

Comment: @Stijn: You are not developing for VS specifically. Tagging the tool you use, clutters the meaning. Imagine every Java question was tagged with Eclipse, or Ruby with Vim ;p Also the command line compiler is perfectly capable of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a package to be able to use `async` and `await` in .NET 4.0 projects.

But be aware. I encountered the problem where these libraries cannot be used in .NET 4.5 projects. But this was before the initial release of .NET 4.5. Therefore this problem might be resolved.

Comment: So there is no need to use the package on 4.5, am i right?

Comment: @JohanTG correct, there is no need to use them in 4.5. A typical use-case might be in, say, a NuGet package that targets both 4.0 and 4.5, with the 4.0 dll using `Bcl.Async`, and the 4.5 dll just using the inbuilt types.

Comment: @xxMUROxx as far as I know, there is no problem taking a NuGet dependency on them in 4.5, since the 4.5 package is essentially empty. However, if you manually add a reference to the 4.0 tools, or add the reference while 4.0 and then change the project to 4.5 without fixing the NuGet dependency, then it might cause problems. Of course, there is also no *need* to add such a dependency in 4.5, since it adds nothing.

Answer (score 18):

`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` provides the runtime types that the C# 5.0 compiler needs to use `async` and `await`.

It brings `async`/`await` support to .NET 4.0, Silverlight 4 and 5, Windows Phone Silverlight 7.1/7.5, *and portable libraries* that include any of those platforms. It also provides some extension methods on the Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0 platform, so it's sometimes used there even though WP8 can support `async`/`await` without it.

It does *not* include the ASP.NET runtime changes necessary for proper `async`/`await` support, so if you install it into an ASP.NET 4.0 project, the code will compile but will not work correctly. The only supported way to use `async`/`await` on ASP.NET is to upgrade to 4.5.

Comment: Really trying to understand this because I'm working on a project in .Net4.0 and I want to use async. At first glance this package is exactly what we need. But
> the code will compile but will not work correctly. Then what on earth is the point of this package it's just to pretend? 
> It brings async/await support to .NET 4.0.
But only for the editor and meanwhile the code will not work? If 4.5 includes async/await then what on earth is the point of this package?

Comment: @YehudaMakarov: This package is for enabling `async`/`await` for .NET 4.0, for all project types *except* ASP.NET. So it's for Console apps, WinForms apps, WPF apps, Silverlight apps, and Windows Phone SL apps. Just not ASP.NET apps.